# How to check if a button is clicked in wxpython with a conditional 'if - else' statement?

Tags: wxpython

So I am making a program where I only want to display a line in my plot when the user clicks a button. I know that you can do something similar with checkboxes such as checkbox.IsChecked(), which will output a boolean value. Similarly, I have used the wx.ID_OK for checking text entry into a text dialog box with ShowModal().

```
box = wx.TextEntryDialog(...)
if box.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
                ...some code
box.Destroy()
```

Is there something similar, such as:

```
if some_button.SomeMethod() == button.IsClicked():
                  ...some code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you just bind the button to an event handler like this:

```
some_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onHandler)
```

Then when the button is pressed, the event is fired and the `onHandler` method is called. If you'd rather have something like a checkbox, then you might want to check out the ToggleButton:

- http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/ToggleButton.html